# Converting while loop from C to MIPS

Tags: c, mips

I just started to learn the basics of MIPS. While reading a book about MIPS I thought about the next question:

I have the following code:

```
while (x) {...}
```

What's between brackets isn't important (just put dots on the right place on the code). It is know that x contains a Boolean statement. Let reg $t0 contain x. I am trying to convert this C while loop into a MIPS code. How to do so?

Comment: Consider getting some free software cross-compiler (e.g. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), maybe you would compile its source code) then studying the generated assembler code: `mipsel-linux-gnu-gcc -O2 -fverbose-asm -S`; using the `gcc-mipsel-linux-gnu` cross-compiler package on my Debian

Comment: Will do. It just a random question that came to my mind while I was reading about MIPS

Comment: convert the while loop in C using only `goto` then you'll know how to do that in MIPS

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a branch and a label. For example, the statement

`while (n>0) { .... }`

can be translated to MIPS using a branch and a label:

```
    .data

    n: .word 100

    .text

    main:

    la $t0, n   
    lw $t1, 0($t0)
    li $s0, 0

    Loop:
       bgt $t1, $zero, EXIT
       add $t1, $s0, $t1
       addi $t1, $t1, -1

       j Loop

   EXIT:
```

Comment: I need for more general statement. It doesn't really matter what the statement is, just that's a Boolean statement. Consider x to be the statement. How do I represent x?

Comment: _"Consider x to be the statement."_ You mean _expression_? _"How do I represent x?"_ By the necessary code that computes the value of the expression. That's about as specific as one can put it really.